# How can I call a function when the screen is being navigated by other screen with passing variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have issue while handling React Native Lifecycle whereby I have a function call "getData()" should be load before render() method is being triggered.
I have tested to applied "ComponentDidMount" but it does not work because the component does not being render.
As I know, the sequence of the RN lifecycle will be :

1. constructor()
2. static getDerivedStateFromProps()
3. render()
4. componentDidMount()

I was thinking am I able to put the function inside the constructor but I get a warning indication and the function is not loaded once the screen is being navigated or startup.
Does anyone know how can I preload the function before the render occurs?

Below are my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Modal,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    TouchableOpacity,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
import CustomHeader from './CustomHeader';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { StackActions } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import { Form, Label, Body, Item, Text, Right, Left, Footer, Icon, List, Container, Spinner, ListItem, Content, CheckBox, Button, H3, H2, H1 } from 'native-base';
import Moment from 'moment';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ApiURL } from "../constants/master";

class TransactionDetailScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            restaurantName: '',
            transactionDetails: [],
            transactionId: '',
            total: 0.00,
            mode: ''
        }
        this.loadTransactionDetails();
    }

    loadTransactionDetails() {
        
        if (this.props.navigation.state.params){
            this.setState({transactionId:this.props.navigation.state.params.transactionId});
            const id = this.props.navigation.state.params.transactionId;
        console.log(`id:${id}`);
        console.log(`${ApiURL}/transaction/${id}`);
        axios.get(`${ApiURL}/transaction/${id}`)
            .then(resp => {
                if (resp.status === 200){
                    const res = resp.data.info;
                    this.setState({transactionDetails:res,mode:res.mode});
                }
                else{
                    alert(resp.data.error);
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                alert("err:" + error.message)
            });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params);
        this.loadTransactionDetails();
           
    }

    static navigationOptions = () => ({
        headerShown: false
    })

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <CustomHeader isHome={false} navigation={this.props.navigation} backScene="Transaction" title="Transaction Detail" />
                <Content style={{ backgroundColor: "#f8f9fa" }}>
                    <ListItem itemDivider>
                        <Text>{this.state.mode}</Text>
                    </ListItem>
                    <Grid style={{ backgroundColor: "white", paddingVertical: 15, paddingHorizontal: 15 }}>
                        <Row>
                            <Text style={styles.lgText}>{this.state.transactionDetails.localMsg}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                <View alignItems="flex-end">
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
                                        RM
                                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 35 }}>
                                            {parseFloat(this.state.transactionDetails.amount).toFixed(2)}
                                        </Text>
                                    </Text>

                                </View>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid style={{ backgroundColor: "white", paddingHorizontal: 15, marginTop: 15 }}>
                        <Row style={{ paddingTop: 10 }} >
                            <Col size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colHeading}>{this.state.mode === "Payment" ? "Merchant" : "Payment method"}</Text>
                            </Col>
                            <Col alignItems="flex-end" size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colBody} alignSelf="flex-end">{this.state.mode === "Payment" ? this.state.transactionDetails.merchant : this.state.transactionDetails.paymentMethod}</Text>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={{ paddingTop: 10 }} >
                            <Col size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colHeading}>Date</Text>
                            </Col>
                            <Col alignItems="flex-end" size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colBody} alignSelf="flex-end">{this.state.transactionDetails.createdAt && Moment(this.state.transactionDetails.createdAt).format('L LT')}</Text>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        {
                            this.state.mode === "Payment" && (
                            <Row style={{ paddingTop: 10 }} >
                            <Col size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colHeading}>Order ID</Text>
                            </Col>
                            <Col alignItems="flex-end" size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colBody} alignSelf="flex-end">{this.state.transactionDetails.orderId}</Text>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>)
                        }
                        <Row style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }} >
                            <Col size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colHeading}>Transaction ID</Text>
                            </Col>
                            <Col alignItems="flex-end" size={50}>
                                <Text style={styles.colBody} alignSelf="flex-end">{this.props.navigation.state.params ? this.props.navigation.state.params.transactionId : null}</Text>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>
                    {
                        this.state.mode === "Payment" && (
                            <>
                            <ListItem itemDivider style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
                        <Text>Payment Item</Text>
                    </ListItem>
                    <List style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                        {
                            this.state.transactionDetails.items.map((item,i) => {
                                return (
                                    <ListItem key={i}>
                                        <Body>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Row style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                                                    <Col>
                                                        <Text><H3>{item.name}</H3></Text>
                                                    </Col>
                                                </Row>
                                                <Row style={{ marginBottom: 5 }}>
                                                    <Col><Text style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>RM {parseFloat(item.paidAmount).toFixed(2)}</Text></Col>
                                                </Row>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Body>
                                    </ListItem>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </List>
                            </>
                        )
                    }
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },
    lgText: {
        fontSize: 18
    },
    colHeading: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    colBody: {
        fontSize: 16
    }
});

export default TransactionDetailScreen;
```

Comment: You do not need to fire `this.loadTransactionDetails` in Constructor. Keeping it in `componentDidMount` is fine. Could you share the response received from API? Do you get status 200, json structure, etc.

Comment: The API is not being called if I mount it at componentDidMount

Comment: That's weird. Could you manage to debug and see if the method `this.loadTransactionDetails` is being fired? You need to at least ensure method is getting call and api is fired with 200 status return. Only then, your UI will get renders.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in your case, as it is an API call.

However if you call an API in `constructor`, it will be gone in background and your current component will execute `render()`

So the best way to call it in `componentDidMount()` and than set your state variable accordingly.

Comment: but it does not work in componentDidMount(), if I didn't render anything yet.